# How to scroll to first row in grouped style UITableView?

Tags: uitableview

I have a grouped style UITableView and I would like to scroll to first row in each section. I'm using the following code but that takes me to section header. Is there any way to go to the top of the row instead?

```
[self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:section]
                             atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using contentInsets to achieve this:

```
- (void)jumpToSection:(NSUInteger)section {

    self.autoscrolling = YES;

            // inset the table, so that the section header is hidden when auto-scrolling
            // between sections
            [self.tableView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(-sectionHeaderHeight,0,0,0)];


            [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:section]
                                  atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
}

-(void)scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {

    if (self.autoscrolling) {
        [self removeInsets];
    }

    self.autoscrolling = NO;
}

- (void)removeInsets {
    // remove inset so that all section headers are visible when
    // when scrolling manually
    [self.tableView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0,0,0,0)];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use `scrollRectToVisible` instead. like this

```
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0.f,
                         yOfTargetCell, //Calc first
                         self.tableView.frame.size.width,
                         self.tableView.frame.size.height);
[self.tableView scrollRectToVisible:rect animated:YES];
```

Comment: What's a reliable way to get the y offset of the cell? When I tried to query the frame of cell at indexPath, it just returns CGRectZero.